# Moved to a dedicated server - automated web emails not sending?

Tags: php, email, dns

I recently moved over to a dedicated server. I changed the nameservers on my domain and the new website is now working fantastically. However, automatic emails such as the newly registered confirmation email members are supposed to receive, etc. don't seem to be sending. Why might this be?

I know there are likely to be a wide range of potential causes but if anyone has any suggestions it'd be fantastic to hear them! I used Squirrel Mail to check a couple of the email accounts and both sending and receiving on the new dedicated server seems to be fine.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions! :-)

Comment: Ah, I just found it in spam (didn't even bother looking there as it never used to end up there). Very strange. Anyone have any suggestions to stop it from heading there in future?

Comment: Look in the headers of the spam-mail. Often there are headers explaining why the mail was seen as spam.

Comment: Check your headers to see if there are any spam flags. You can also run the headers through http://www.mxtoolbox.com/emailheaders.aspx to see if there are any flags.

Comment: i allways suggest working through this:http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop php `mail()` being treated as spam mail

You must to add a needle headers:

Sample code :

```
$headers = "From: myplace@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: myplace2@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: myplace@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: sombodyelse@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: hidden@example.com\r\n";

if ( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) ) {
   echo "The email has been sent!";
   } else {
   echo "The email has failed!";
   }
?>
```